# Python - Selenium unresponsive and blocking the program

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with Python. After multiple find and click operations, the script stops executing. When I check, the Selenium will be blocking the entire code, either at a click operation or at a find_element_by_* or some other selenium based code.

Anyone else facing it?

Comment: Show us the code in question, Selenium Webdriver is a working product that lots of people, including me, use in production. It's not simply broken. We will need to see the code.

Comment: The code is big and also very basic. Only a click. There are four functions. Each doing a similar thing. If I restart the webdriver each time, they work fine. They also work any 2 at a time. But after that, the script gets blocked.

Comment: Again, seeing the code would be a big help in us helping you solve this issue.

Comment: Yeah, if you can't show us a minimal example of the code that fails to work then nobody can help. The short answer to your question will just be no. Nobody else is facing it. Because Seleniun works.

Comment: Besides the code, it would also be helpful to know:

* Are you testing on a local or remote instance of Chrome?
* Do any of your scripts stop consistently at one location?

Comment: The code stops at different instances at each time. Generally a click or a send_keys.
I run chromedriver. Its a remote instance.
I can't uplaod the code just yet. sorry about that. I'll do it in a while.